# Replace x with x + divisor of x, starting from 1, to reach target number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, divisibility

How can I find the minimum number of steps to go from initial number i = 1 to a target number n using the following transformation: replace i with i + d, where d divides i.
For example, for n = 7, the steps would be 1->2->4->6->7, so the answer is 4.
What I've tried is to only work with powers of 2, as I did in the previous example: double the number, starting from 1, x times, until 2^(x + 1) > n. Then add smaller powers of 2 until target is reached.
However, this does not always result in an optimal number of steps. For example, for n=30 the steps would be 1->2->4->8->16->24->28->30, so 7 steps. But this can be done in 6 steps, this way: 1->2->4->8->10->20->30.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. One method which I believe will generally work well is to factor your target $n$, then try to get numbers with factors of each of each prime factor in decreasing order, often by adding the product of the factors obtained so far at each step. Thus, for $30 = 5 \times 3 \times 2$, an alternate way to do it in $6$ steps is with $1$ -> $2$ -> $4$ -> $\color{red}{5}$ -> $10$ -> $\color{red}{15}$ -> $\color{red}{30}$. However, I'm not providing this an answer as it's just a heuristic that I don't know whether or not it's always optimal, much less how to prove this if it's true.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you for the answer. I think I got your point, but how does that work if n is a prime?

Comment: You're welcome. For the initial largest prime factor, such as $n$ itself when it's prime, I suggest using something like your idea of using powers of $2$ (i.e., keep doubling until you get to the largest power of $2$ smaller than the target value) could be used to get to that initial factor.

Comment: @JohnOmielan that's exactly what I had in mind as well, but then I saw the fact that this method doesn't work on primes either, unfortunately. For example: for n = 31: with powers of 2: 1->2->4->8->16->24->28->30->31 with 8 steps and 1->2->4->8->10->20->30->31 with 7 steps